# One line doesn't respect right margin

Tags: line-breaking, margins, hyphenation, hyphenat

What could be causing one single line of this text not being aligned to the right (first line of third paragraph)?

[image]

```tex
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[headsep=14pt, paperwidth=14cm, paperheight=21cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{nu-ma}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont

O caracol queria comer a couve, mas a chuva não queria passar. Decidiu então ficar onde estava, protegido sob um pé de rúcula. Adormeceu. Quando a chuva passou e ele despertou, decidiu experimentar um pouco da rúcula. Mas o agricultor não quis colaborar: quando estava chegando perto da verdura, o caracol a viu se elevar subitamente num supetão que chegou a causar um terremoto. O caracol assustou tanto que sua vontade era se esconder e ficar imóvel por horas ali na terra, mas a fome não quis deixar. \par
O caracol avistou um pé de alface e seguiu até ele. Ele já estava na base do vegetal, quase chegando na primeira folha, mas o agricultor, de novo, não quis esperar: arrancou o pé de alface num golpe, tal como tinha feito com a rúcula, e enfiou-o na cesta. O caracol petrificou. Estava ele agora grudado na alface, dentro da cesta escura e abafada e atolada de vegetais, sem espaço para se mover. \par
Chegando na feira, cada verdura foi brevemente lavada numa bacia com água. O banho poderia ter sido suficiente para expulsar o caracol, mas a dona da banca não quis perder mais de um segundo com cada verdura, e o caracol permaneceu grudado na alface dele. \par
Expostos na feira, o caracol e a alface ficariam por horas. Parece que ninguém queria comprar aquela alface. O caracol permanecia discreto e calado na raiz. Duas ou três pessoas o notaram, mas não quiseram fazer nada a respeito. A dona da banca da feira resolveu abaixar os preços, pois não queria voltar com alface para casa. Finalmente, a alface foi comprada. Ela e o caracol foram metidos numa sacola e levados para a casa de alguém.\par
Chegando em casa, a pessoa que comprou a alface decidiu que não queria comer alface naquele dia, então depositou-a na geladeira. Lá ficaram ela e o caracol até o dia seguinte. O caracol não entendia muito bem a situação, ele só sabia que queria sair dali, mas a geladeira não queria abrir. O corpo do caracol estava frio, e sua alma estava congelando. Ele rezava como podia, mas Deus não queria atender.\par
No dia seguinte, à noite, o cozinheiro retirou a alface da geladeira e colocou-a de molho em água misturada a um produto químico que teria matado o caracol, mas o cozinheiro não quis colocar a quantidade suficiente. Tonto, o caracol saiu da água e começou a vagar desorientado pela cozinha. O cozinheiro o viu. O cozinheiro pegou-o de um jeito inadvertidamente desajeitado demais e o colocou para fora, no parapeito da janela, pois não o quis matar.\par
O caracol queria sair dali e caminhar para ver se encontrava de novo a horta. Mas seus músculos não quiseram obedecer. Estavam liquefeitos.\par
A manhã chegou. Chegaram os pássaros. Ao meio-dia, o dia ardia, e a alma do caracol ainda habitava sua nublada consciência. Os pássaros não o quiseram comer. Mas o sol não quis perdoar. O caracol evaporou. \par
Seu casco permanece sólido no mesmo lugar pois ninguém o quis remover. \par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you prefer to use explicit `\par` directives instead of all-blank lines to generate paragraph breaks?

Comment: What we have here is a failure to hyphenate.

Comment: @Mico Just so the code snippet doesn't have too many blank lines.

Comment: @Raphael - You really only had to post one paragraph, not nine. :-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Nice allusion to *Cool Hand Luke*. :-)

Comment: @Mico Haha, I wanted to show the error only occurred once.

Answer (score 3):

The preamble instruction `\hyphenation{nu-ma}` has no effect because with `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}`, we also have `\righthyphenmin=3`, meaning that 3 or more letters must be present *to the right* of a hyphenation point. Clearly, "numa" doesn't satisfy this condition if hyphenation is supposed to occur between "nu" and "ma".

To override this setting and thus to allow LaTeX to hyphenate "numa" if necessary, you need to change `numa` to `nu\-ma`. I would *not* recommend setting `\righthyphenmin=2`, as doing so almost certainly invites making hyphenation mistakes in other words in the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=14cm, paperheight=21cm, 
            headsep=14pt, left=2cm, right=2cm,
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
% \hyphenation{nu-ma} %% has no effect

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont

Chegando na feira, cada verdura foi brevemente 
lavada nu\-ma bacia com água. O banho poderia 
ter sido suficiente para expulsar o caracol, 
mas a dona da banca não quis perder mais de 
um segundo com cada verdura, e o caracol 
permaneceu grudado na alface dele.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting! But then, why doesn't the algorithm choose to break before the word?

Comment: @Raphael - TeX's hyphenation and line-breaking algorithm is famously (and uniquely too, across all software-based implementations of hyphenation and line breaking algorithms) entire-paragraph-oriented, not line-by-line oriented. All I can surmise is that TeX must have decided that inserting a line break *before* "numa" would lead to even bigger compromises elsewhere in the paragraph; thus, absent the `nu\-ma` compromise, inserting a line-break after "numa" was the lesser of several evils.

Comment: I just found out that I can use `\emergencystretch 1em` to have it break before the word.

Comment: I tried `\righthyphenmin=2` (as you discouraged) and I can agree that the rest of the text looks ugly.